# SQL Server column date default gatedate() to datetime in scripts

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Note> I can not modify old scripts!!!**

First script create table TABLENAME.

I have table TABLENAME with column COLUMNNAME DATE DEFAULT GETDATE();

I need to do: ->

```
ALTER TABLE TABLENAME 
ALTER COLUMN COLUMNNAME DATETIME;
```

I get a error:

> The object 'DF__TABLENAME__COLUMNNAME__7BC8385B' is dependent on column 'COLUMNNAME'.

I have this scripts on multiple databases so this part **'DF__TABLENAME__COLUMNNAME__7BC8385B'**

is on every database different.

I can make

```
ALTER TABLE TABLENAME 
DROP CONSTRAINT DF__TABLENAME__COLUMNNAME__7BC8385B;
```

And it will work, but It will not be very effective use it manually on all DB, I need make the script which will alter this column on everywhere without needed to know that constraint name.

Comment: I don't fully follow what you actually want to do here, but dynamic SQL is probably the solution.  Basically, you can build a query string using variables as input, then execute it.

Comment: I need change date to datetime, in script, but I cant do it because this column has constraint, and on every DB this constrain has different name so I have no idea how to change it, because I cant alter because error / object is dependent, and i cant drop constraint because i dont know exact name.

Comment: Looks like someone hasn';t been naming their constraints if it has a name like `DF__TABLENAME__COLUMNNAME__7BC8385B`. Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Yes this constraint was created after i used Default gatdate()

Comment: Get the constraint name from the dictionary, build a statement dropping it using that data and execute it. That's the dynamic SQL part. Then change the column and recreate the constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've got variable constraint names you'll have to generate the change script per database. If you've got faith in this you can put the resulting script into an [sp_executesql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) call.

This is using the sys views to query the database structure and generate the script in the last result column.

```
declare @TableName nvarchar(128) = 'TABLENAME';
declare @ColumnName nvarchar(128) = 'COLUMNNAME';

SELECT t.name [table], c.name [column], typ.name [type]
, def.name [DefaultConstraint], def.definition [DefaultValue]
, 'ALTER TABLE [' + t.name + '] DROP CONSTRAINT [' + def.name + ']; ALTER TABLE [' + t.name + '] ALTER COLUMN [' + c.name + '] DATETIME; ALTER TABLE [' + t.name + '] ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_' + t.name + '_' + c.name + '] DEFAULT getdate() FOR [' + c.name + '];'
FROM sys.columns c
JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
JOIN sys.types typ on c.user_type_id=typ.user_type_id
LEFT JOIN sys.default_constraints def on c.default_object_id=def.object_id
WHERE typ.name = 'date'
and t.name = @TableName and c.name = @ColumnName
order by t.name, c.name
```